# Uso de jquery para puxar registros, mas não aparece

Tags: php, html, jquery, banco-de-dados

Vi num tutorial do celke, dar select no BD usando php e listar os registros utilizando jquery. Consigo ver que puxou os dados, mas na hora de mostrar dentro do span não mostra. Gostaria de saber onde errei, e como puxo outros registros, pois tem varios checkbox pra filtrar e ao clicar neles quero que dê um select no banco e me traga essa informação la e que eu possa estilizar ela.

(A *home.php* está dentro de uma pasta, e a index em outra(pasta raiz), não sei se é por isso que não ler, e não sei como entrar dentro da outra pasta, uso netbeans)

**HTML**

`<span id="conteudo"></span>`

**JQUERY**

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.post('home.php', function(retorna)
                $("#conteudo").html(retorna);
        });

                });
    </script>
```

**PHP**

```
$consulta_bd = "SELECT * FROM uniao";  
  $result=pg_query($conexao, $consulta_bd);  
  if  (($result)){  
      while($linha_usuario = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){    
          echo $linha_usuario['cd_regua'] . "<br>";  
}  
    }   else      
{  
      echo "Nenhum resultado encontrado";  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $.ajax({
            url: "/home.php",  // coloque aqui o endereço que vai buscar os dados no banco         
            success: function (data) {                                  
                $('#conteudo').html(data); 
                $('#conteudo').show(); // Mostrar o retorno em texto no html

            },
            error: function (request, status, erro) {

                $('#conteudo').html('Ocorreu um erro, entre em contato com T.I!', erro);
                $('#conteudo').show();

            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {              

            }
        });
```

Comment: Eu fiz a primeira etapa, usei jquery para monitorar o evento do checkbox, "Ao clicar no checkbox 'regua', consultar o banco de dados e trazer o registro 'regua' que está lá". Logo após monitorar se for "checked", faça a consulta no BD e me retorne dentro de um flexbox. Sempre que marcar o chexbox me traga aquele dado. Sabe me dizer como coloco dentro do jquery pra me trazer essa consulta logo após a marcação no checkbox?